# How to Run an EXE using Powershell with a wildcard to find the file?

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to run an exe on different devices using PowerShell. The issue is the exe is named slightly differently. Below is an example of my current code which works:

`Start-Process -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\theapp*\runme-'bhkjsa080as'.exe"`

I want to change this so it target the differently named exe files and runs them. Below is a failed example:

`Start-Process -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\theapp*\runme*"`

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

NVM

Got it

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\theapp*
*.exe"